# Searching a MySQL Database on ClearDB using Python script

Tags: python, mysql, database, search, cleardb

We have built a series a forms using PHP that populate a MySQL Database and after learning more Python want to begin transitioning our whole web app over to a python back end instead of PHP. Can anyone offer a quick intro into searching a MySQL DB using Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to abstract the database using an ORM. I found that the python package SQLAlchemy works fantastically.

A ORM let's you treat the database objects as normal python objects. Most queries can be abstracted and for 99% of cases you won't need to write SQL queries. Also this makes transition between database technologies very simple.

Go check it out on:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/

A search query would be something like:

```
session.query(User).filter_by(first_name='bob')
```

Now you will have all users with the first name 'bob'

Comment: does SQLalchemy work with 2.7.3? I notice the brackets and am curious if that is the syntax for python 3+

Comment: @mcclaskiem, yes I used it in a 2.7 project.

Answer (score 0):

You search it the same way you would in PHP; because the queries you are using will not change.

The only difference is the [driver you have to use](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#mysqldb).